java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "accessFlags" because the return value of "com.android.tools.r8.graph.AppView.definitionFor" is null
Getting this error after updating the Android Gradle Plugin from 7.2.1 to 8.0.2
Android studio - Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1
Kotlin version - 1.9.23
Java - 17
Crash log -
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_8.3.37.java:0)
    at com.android.tools.r8.InternalCompilationFailedExceptionUtils.create(InternalCompilationFailedExceptionUtils.java:29)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.failWithFakeEntry(ExceptionUtils.java:145)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.failCompilation(ExceptionUtils.java:89)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:83)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withR8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:69)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.runForTesting(R8.java:238)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.run(R8.java:194)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.R8Tool.runR8(r8Tool.kt:335)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$Companion.shrink(R8Task.kt:730)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable.execute(R8Task.kt:806)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "accessFlags" because the return value of "com.android.tools.r8.graph.AppView.definitionFor(com.android.tools.r8.graph.DexType)" is null
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.optimize.SwitchMapCollector.extractSwitchMap(SwitchMapCollector.java:154)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.optimize.SwitchMapCollector.lambda$processClasses$0(SwitchMapCollector.java:102)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.optimize.SwitchMapCollector.processClasses(SwitchMapCollector.java:102)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.optimize.SwitchMapCollector.run(SwitchMapCollector.java:82)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.run(R8.java:522)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.run(R8.java:251)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.lambda$runForTesting$1(R8.java:242)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:80)
    ... 35 more

I tried using the latest R8 version 8.3.37 but still getting the same error.
pluginManagement {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url = uri("https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw")
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("com.android.tools:r8:8.3.37")
            classpath('com.google.guava:guava:33.2.0-jre')
        }
    }
}


Looks like R8 is processing a SwitchMap on a missing enum. Do you have a reproduction project for the issue? Normally R8 throws if some referenced classes are missing from the input, do you run with ignorewarnings in your keep rules (a.k.a. proguard configuration)?
I opened b/341991457 in the Google buganizer. I (R8 developer here) will try to make a reproduction, I guess it's ok for R8 to bail out from the switch map optimization in this case, but it would be better if I could reproduce directly your error from a sample project. Not sure how far this can be backported though.

Thanks for the reply @clementbera. Tried with ignorewarnings but still the same error. Also I don't have a reproduction project for this and the code base is big so I'm not able to identify the part of code which might be causing this.

I made a fix for 8.6 (under review). I don't think I can backport further than 8.5.
I think the problem is that you're already running with ignorewarnings, if you remove it from your keep rules (i.e. proguard configuration), you will see the list of missing classes, the problem comes from one of the enum class being missing. To fix your issue, you need to add the missing enum class to your compilation (Maybe a dependency is missing from the input or something like that).

Right! I found that there was a -dontwarn **.* added into the proguard file which was causing the Missing classes errors to be ignored. I'm able to see the missing classes after removing that.
